# git on Linux uploading files from another repository too

Tags: linux, git, github

I have 2 git repositories, one with 3 files and another one with the same 3 files but similar content. (Like README.md, index.html, etc.)

I used "git add" to add the files and created 2 remotes named "view" and "music". 
I added the 3 first files in the first folder with "git add" and commited+pushed them to the view repository.
Then I went to the other folder, added those 3 files with "git add" too and commit+pushed them too, but i suddenly have the other 3 files pushed too. 
(The repository "music" has the files from "view" too)

TL;DR: How can I seperate git repositories on Linux

Running CentOS 7 and the newest git update available via yum.
I already tried making 2 different folders and writing "git init" before using the "git add" and other commands to commit + push.
They still returned an error instead of posting duplicates.

The following was used in both folders, but errors happened on the second folder

```
echo "# testing" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.Username/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```

I expected that git would somehow distinguish between multiple repositories, and that I can simply have 2 folders with 2 repositories.
I thought after a git push / commit the "git add array" of files would be empty again and I could add new files for another git commit / push.
How can I commit/push to multiple repositories via the Linux Command Line and push different files to different repositores without them getting mixed up.

EDIT:

The folder structure is as follows:

```
[usr@servr~]$ ls music/
index.html  README.md  songs
[usr@servr~]$ ls view/
index.html  README.md  pics
```

The exact steps I did:

```
cd music
git init; git add README.md; git add index.html; git add songs
git commit -m "Initial Commit"; git remote add origin <link2music>; git push -u music master
cd ../view
git add README.md; git add index.html; git add songs; git commit -m "Initial Commit"; git remote add origin <link2view>; git push -u view master
```

Then the git repository of view suddenly had the README.md of the music repository, and the folder songs too (even though it shouldnt).

I deleted the view repository but kept the music repository on github. (No folder deleted on my Linux machine). I then tried to exactly enter the code from the first snippet (the github offical one) in both folders (with git init too in each folder) and now the music repository, which already existed, threw me the error "! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)", even though i never deleted the music repository, neither from my machine nor from github. (files are the same on both)

Comment: Which errors happened on the second folder? Also, is one repository located in a subfolder of the other?

Comment: Are the two repositories truly separate? Control questions: 1) Do the directory structures overlap, like is one of the two repositories a parent of the other? 2) Are you using symbolic links, to share folders? 3) Could it be that you simply messed up and copied the other files as well?

Comment: To be clear, if the two repositories are truly separate, then they're truly separate. Git will treat them separately, there is nothing you should have to do to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone recommended me to try `git status`, and with that I found out that my problem was the upper-level folder. I accidentally made the upper level folder, above my 2 "repo"-folders, a git repository.

How it should be:

```
Home
->music(repo .git)
->view(repo .git)
```

Hot it was (bad):

```
Home (repo .git)
->music
->view
```

That means that I didn't push the 2 folders to their respective repositories, but I instead pushed the upper-level folder (my home folder) to the repositories, which of course contained both of my other folders.

I deleted the .git folder from my home, cloned my git repos in a different folder again, and now they work as intended.